# Still confused about docker

Tags: docker

Ive taken an app and built a docker image for windows server 2016 using `microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0` base image.
My question is...what machines/OS's will I be able to run the container on?
I know it cant run on Linux.....but could it run on (e.g.) ANY version of windows server 2016?  How about windows server 2019?
The architecture is AMD64....does that mean the container will only run on machines with that exact architecture?

Im trying to figure out why containers are considered beneficial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with Docker Windows containers, but I have a ton of experience with Docker containers in general, and the concepts between Windows and Linux containers should be mostly the same.

When you run your built app, no matter if you run it on Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2019, or even Windows 10 Pro, the app *should* function exactly the same. Under the covers, Docker provides an isolated application environment. From your applications perspective, it only knows/experiences/sees itself and the Windows Kernel that it's running on. If you had, say, an IIS instance also running on that server, your app would have no idea. The point here is that Docker provides a means to:

1. Run multiple versions of an app on the same machine, in complete isolation.
2. Have a more clean running environment for every app.
3. Be much more resource efficient than running discrete VMs

Another huge benefit of Docker is that it provides a means to ephemeral environments. Which means you should expect to have the *exact* same behavior from an app running on machine #1 as you do on machine #2. It eliminates the "works on my machine" mentality, especially when some other 3rd party dependency is not installed/forgotten, because these will be bundled into the container as part of the build.

Lastly, about architecture. The app you built is designed to run against the architecture of the Windows Kernel it was built with. In your case AMD64, from my understanding, this implies the x86_64 architecture. This should mean that your container will run on any 64-bit x86 machine (AMD or Intel). Your container will not run on any other architecture: x86 (32 bit), 386, 486, ARM, ARM 64, etc. I think in the case of Windows this isn't as important of an issue, because 90% of the time you're running on x86_64. But with Linux you end up with everything from SPARC to ARM, and so that architecture distinction is important.

I too had a lot of the same questions when I started using docker. While the product "Docker" has been hit-or-miss on occasion, the concept "containers" and the benefits they provide when used correctly are very powerful and I use the for almost every project I work on.

Comment: Really like the comment about "it only knows/experiences/sees itself and the Windows Kernel that it's running on"......that brought much needed clarity to me.

Comment: Glad I could help, @jamesmurphy. I haven't read this article fully yet, but I believe it will give you some excellent back-story to a lot of the concepts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/april/containers-bringing-docker-to-windows-developers-with-windows-server-containers